# Heira Puppet erb syntax for collection object

Tags: puppet, erb, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache

Our Yaml.

```
  scopeConfigs: 
    - {resource: '/users', scopes: ['demographicProfile','basicProfile']}
```

Id like to know how to declare this on heira also on erb

Ive tried putting it on heira

```
scope_configs: "[{'resource':'/users', 'scopes': {'basicProfile', 'demographicProfile'}},{'resource':'/users2', 'scopes': {'basicProfile', 'demographicProfile'}}]"
```

and for the erb we tried

```
  scopeConfigs: 
    <% scope_configs.each do |config| %>
    - {resource: <%= config.resource %>, scopes: <%= config.scopes %>}
    <% end %>
```

but still no luck, im getting Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to push data into Hiera using Java?

Comment: No, our java app uses puppet that gets the value from heira, our problem is identifying the right syntax for erb and heira.. ive updated our latest code experiment, but still no luck

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not clear to be what you're trying to do.  You have a Java app that uses Puppet - how does it use Puppet?  Via its REST API?  Via its command line?  If it's using Puppet, why would your Java app be trying to deserialise after reading ERB.  Puppet should read the ERB.  So you'll need to add some info about your expectations of data flow.